# Php quiz how to add value to the weight of the answer

Tags: php

I've used this page to create my own quiz

https://css-tricks.com/building-a-simple-quiz/

For this example each question is worth 1 point.
I would like to change each question to say 10points.

I have tried changing the value and have had no luck, 
Any ideas?

```
<?php 

$answer1 = $_POST['question-1-answers']; 
$answer2 = $_POST['question-2-answers']; 
$answer3 = $_POST['question-3-answers']; 
$answer4 = $_POST['question-4-answers']; 
$answer5 = $_POST['question-5-answers']; 

$totalCorrect = 0; 

if ($answer1 == "A") { $totalCorrect++; } 
if ($answer1 == "B") { $totalCorrect++; } 
if ($answer2 == "A") { $totalCorrect++; } 
if ($answer3 == "C") { $totalCorrect++; } 
if ($answer4 == "D") { $totalCorrect++; } 
if ($answer5) { $totalCorrect++; } 

echo "<div id='results'>$totalCorrect / 100%</div>"

?>
```

Comment: any code to help you with?

Comment: http://www.vestedutility.com.au/home_safety_check.php is where i have it

Comment: You shoud post your code "within" the "Question" body usign formatting tags to meke it more "readable".

Comment: I answered this, but also down voted. It is very easy to search for this answer. Search before posting a question.

Comment: i did try and search for the answer, and couldnt find it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$totalCorrect` is getting incremented 1 per correct answer.

Just change `$totalCorrect++` to `$totalCorrect +=10;` (this is equivalent to `$totalCorrect=$totalCorrect+10`) for an increment of 10 points.

Read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php) for more info on increment operators

Answer (score 1):

Change all the

```
$totalCorrect++;
```

to

```
$totalCorrect += 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends how much questions you are going to ask and what the total sum will be of them. 10 questions of 10 points each are 100 points. In that case you can simple increment $totalCorrect by 10 points by doing `$totalCorrect += 10;`.

BUT, if you have any scenario where the total sum of all points is not 100, then you should add some extra code to show the percentage of correct results.

Allow me to suggest some change to the code:
It still can use some improvement but gives you an idea where to go to.

```
$questions = array(
    '1' => array('answer' => 'A', 'weight' => 10),
    '2' => array('answer' => 'B', 'weight' => 20),
    '3' => array('answer' => 'A', 'weight' => 5),
    '4' => array('answer' => 'A', 'weight' => 15),
);

$points_good = 0;
$total_points = 0;

foreach($questions as $idx => $question)
{
    if(isset($_POST['question-'.$idx.'-answers']))
    {
        $answer = $_POST['question-'.$idx.'-answers'];
        if($answer == $question['answer'])
        {
             $points_good += $question['weight'];
        }
    }
    $total_points += $question['weight'];
}

$totalCorrect = round($points_good / $total_points * 100)
echo "<div id='results'>$totalCorrect / 100%</div>"
```